# How to configure Gzip for JBoss?

Tags: json, http, jboss, gzip, jboss-portal

I think to try to speed up my Web App by reducing the size of transferred data. For example, in Nginx there is a special module. How to enable compression for JBoss server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### JBoss AS version 6 or lower

To enable gzip compression, settings need to be added to your existing HTTP connector. 
Located at `/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml`:

```
<!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="${jboss.web.http.port}"
        address="${jboss.bind.address}" redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}"

compression="force"
compressionMinSize="512"
noCompressionUserAgents=""
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript"
/>
```

### JBoss AS 7.0.x

**JBoss 7.0.x - 7.1.0 have no support for gzip compression build in**. 
See also issue report at: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2991

One way to add gzip compression in JBoss 7.0 is to add is as filter. 
For details: https://code.google.com/p/webutilities/wiki/CompressionFilter

### JBoss AS 7.1.1

Just recently JBoss finished adding gzip compression to JBoss. As of version 7.1.1Final, gzip compression is supported out of the box again. To enable, add to the server launch params:

```
-Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
```

Comment: Hi @Rob Juurlink, Could you explain difference between using of com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CompressionFilter and GZip?

Comment: For JBoss AS 4.2 the server.xml is located at `/server/default/jboss-web.deployer`